# Why does composer autoload not work on macOS Docker containers?

Tags: macos, docker-compose, composer-php, autoload

The file structure is as follows:

```
index.php
composer.json
composer.lock
-lib
--books
---SearchClient.php (contains class books\SearchClient
```

The following docker-compose.yml + PHP works on Windows:

```
{
    "name"             : "keithdavis/books",
    "description"      : "",
    "version"          : "0.1",
    "minimum-stability": "beta",
    "require"          : {
        "ext-curl"         : "*",
        "ext-json"         : "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
    },
    "autoload"         : {
        "psr-4": {
            "books\\": "lib"
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?php

use books\SearchClient;

require_once __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";
$oSearchClient = new SearchClient();
```

However, on macOS (Mojave):

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'books\SearchClient' not found in /var/www/html/search.php on line 6
( ! ) Error: Class 'books\SearchClient' not found in /var/www/html/search.php on line 6
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  416944  {main}( )   .../search.php:0
```

In debugging, it appears the path "lib" is the problem, but I've tried "/lib" and that does not work either. I think maybe I have Composer installed incorrectly. I'm an experienced PHP developer on Windows, but relatively new to Mac and so I'm not 100% about the best way to install Composer on Mac. I followed these instructions globally:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Comment: I don't see why this should work on Windows, but it seems your autoload config should look like this: `books\\": "lib/books"` Otherwise your class would have to be in the `books\books` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your file structure the namespace for you search client class would need to be 
`namespace books\books;`

This is because you are setting the namespace book on the lib folder. Instead of using book twice in the namespace you could point the autoloader directly to the book folder by adding

```
{
    "name"             : "keithdavis/books",
    "description"      : "",
    "version"          : "0.1",
    "minimum-stability": "beta",
    "require"          : {
        "ext-curl"         : "*",
        "ext-json"         : "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
    },
    "autoload"         : {
        "psr-4": {
            "books\\": "lib/books"
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you run `composer dumpautoload` when changing the autoload so that you rebuild the namespaces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that works in both, but as mentioned in the comment above, strange that it ever worked in Windows.